# Java 1D array buttons used as image

Tags: java, jframe

I am trying to set up a 1D Button array with images linked to it.   The following code is my attempt. I am now getting a Array index out of bounds exception error. What am I doing wrong? I am new to Java.  I have place the following code to initialize the new array as a JButton.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;



public class Tutorial extends JFrame
{
       JPanel jp = new JPanel();
    //   JPanel jp2= new JPanel();
       JButton[] jb= new JButton[8];




       public Tutorial()
       {
           setTitle("Roger");
           setVisible(true);
           setSize(1000, 400);
           setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
              //This is the new code suggested by Mad programmer my execution my be wrong
           jb[0]=new JButton();
           jb[1]=new JButton();
           jb[2]=new JButton();
          jb[3]=new JButton();
          jb[4]=new JButton();
          jb[5]=new JButton();
          jb[6]=new JButton();
          jb[7]=new JButton();
          jb[8]=new JButton();

              for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
              {
              jb[i].setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\danie\\eclipse-workspace\\TicTacToe\\images\\Red roger.png"));
              jp.add(jb[i]);
              }


              add(jp);
              validate();
       }

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
             Tutorial t = new Tutorial();
       }
}
```

Comment: You're not initialisation the element in the array before you try and use it

Comment: Hi Mad Programmer can you clarify with an example?

Comment: You need to initialize each JButton element in your array. jb[i] = new JButton();

Comment: Sorry I am new to Java but I still not getting it right.   The code above has been changed to my interpretation of what you are suggesting and it is giving me array index out of bounds exception error.

Comment: You need to do `new JButton[9]` for 9 buttons with highest index 8.

Comment: Sorry Jump that is not the problem still getting array index out of bounds error.